# How can I center my Date input field using aspx?

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm working with code that was created back in 08. I'm trying to center this date input and whenever I do so the span still ends up at the top of the table.

How can I get this input field to stay centered in this table?

[image: Date Field]

Here is the code sample I'm working with:

```html
  <td valign="top" class="style1">
                <div id="patientFilterDiv" style="width: 280px; height: 390px;" class="nonScrollingDiv1">
                    <span id="spnDateFields">
                        <table align="center" class='listStyle1'>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="spnBeginDate">Begin Date</span>&nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="spntxtBeginDate">
                                        <input id="beginDate" type="text" runat="server" name="beginDate" style="width: 72px;"></span>&nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="spnBeginDateImage">
                                        <img id="selectBeginDate" onclick="SelectBeginDate();" src="../../Images/calendar.gif"
                                            style="cursor: hand" /></span>&nbsp;
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span id="spnEndDate">End Date</span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="endDate" type="text" runat="server" name="endDate" style="width: 72px;">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <img id="selectEndDate" onclick="SelectEndDate();" src="../../Images/calendar.gif"
                                        style="cursor: hand" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </span>
                    <span id="spnMonthliesOnly">
                        <table align="center" class='listStyle1'>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="majorsOnly" type="checkbox" />Monthlies Only</br> <span style="display: none">
                                        <input id="chkEndOfMonth" type="checkbox" />Last Test Of The Month</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you do realize that a rather nice built-in date picker exists by setting the text mode of the text box, say like this:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"
        TextMode="Date" Width="120px">
    </asp:TextBox>
```

and you thus get this:

[image]

Regardless, you can center the text in that text box by adding text-align with this:

```
        <input id="endDate" type="text" 
            runat="server" 
            name="endDate" 
            style="width:92px;text-align:center;">
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you taking the time and answering this question for me! :)